# How to extract the date of the received emails in Outlook using Python scripting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, outlook

I am new to Python and I developed a Python script to ping messages in an application called Spark. So far, the code is fine and I managed to generate the subject of the emails. But I also want to add the date when I received the email along with the subject. Here is the script :-

```
import win32com.client
import requests
import time
import datetime
def postMessageInSpark(mytoken, roomId, text):
    header = {'Authorization':mytoken, 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    payload = {'roomId':roomId,'text':text}
    result = requests.post(url='https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages',headers=header,json=payload)
    print(str(result.status_code))
    return str(result.status_code)
token ="Bearer "+'OGU3MDcyMmYtZDUzYS00OWU4LTk0ZTItYTJlNTc1OTUzODA5ZmQzYmRkNjMtYzcy'
teamId='Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNGZjYWI5NzAtZGNhMS0xMWU2LWE3ODItYTM1OTY2OWNkMzcx'
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
folders = inbox.Folders
for folder in folders:
 if (folder.Name == 'TES FOLDER'):
  items = folder.Items
  for item in items:
   subject=item.Subject
   message=item.GetLast()
   date=message.senton.date()  
   for idx in reversed(items):
    fail_msg=subject+date
    postMessageInSpark(token,teamId,fail_msg)
    break
```

I used `date=message.senton.date()` but it doesn't return me the date of the emails. Please help me.

Comment: can you correct the indenting? Tip: copy-paste from your code, select the code you just pasted and hit ctrl-k

Comment: is that fine @hansaplast?

Comment: what does `message.senton.date()` return?

Comment: Sorry that was an old code. Please check the updated one. Actually that's the part I am stuck at, I want that variable to return the date or time I received the message at.

Comment: can you do a `print(message.senton.date())` and add the output of that to your question?

Comment: also: did you find any api documentation on this? Because I have no way of reproducing the code, the only thing I can do is point you to the right API doc, **if** I could find the api doc

Comment: @hansaplast actually even I don't have a documentation of this. But I found the solution. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi I found a solution to my problem:-

```
import win32com.client
import requests
import time
import datetime
def postMessageInSpark(mytoken, roomId, text):
    header = {'Authorization':mytoken, 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    payload = {'roomId':roomId,'text':text}
    result = requests.post(url='https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages',headers=header,json=payload)
    print(str(result.status_code))
    return str(result.status_code)
token ="Bearer "+'OGU3MDcyMmYtZDUzYS00OWU4LTk0ZTItYTJlNTc1OTUzODA5ZmQzYmRkNjMtYzcy'
teamId='Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNGZjYWI5NzAtZGNhMS0xMWU2LWE3ODItYTM1OTY2OWNkMzcx'
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
folders = inbox.Folders
for folder in folders:
 if (folder.Name == 'TES FOLDER'):
  items = folder.Items
  for item in reversed(items):
   subject=item.Subject
   date = item.SentOn.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
   for idx in reversed(items):
    fail_msg=subject+" at "+date
    postMessageInSpark(token,teamId,fail_msg)
    idx.Move(inbox.Folders("TEST"))
    break
```

Actually the  `message=item.GetLast()` and `date=message.senton.date()` was only giving me the output of the last email received. But after I used `date = item.SentOn.strftime("%d-%m-%y")` it gave me the output I desired.

Answer (score 1):

`MailItem` object does not have a method called `GetLast`. Only `Items` object does. Did you mean to use `item.SentOn` property?

Comment: Yes it was item.SentOn property. I modified my code a bit and its working now.